# What would you call someone who sneaks into and stays in places where they have to be signed up, e.g. classes/country clubs

Tags: word-request

At my school I used to be in athletics class even though I didn’t sign up or paid to be there, I just simply started acting as if I was part of the team. How would you call a person like that?

Comment: In the running community, people are called [**bandits**](https://www.runnersworld.com/road-scholar/i-bandit) when they run the course but haven't registered for the race. However, I don't know of that word being used in classrooms and such.

Answer (score 55):

An informal term for this is **gate-crasher**.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gatecrasher),

> gate-crasher
>
> noun, Informal.
>
> 1. a person who attends or enters a social function without an invitation, a theater without a ticket, etc.

There is also the verb [gate-crash](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gate-crash). As already noted, the shorted form **crash** is often used.

Comment: Frankly, I ain't never heard it for a theater. And believe me, I would have heard it since at one time was scalping theater tickets in NYC.

Comment: @Lambie Honestly, I can't recall hearing of gate-crashers at a performance in a theater (they're mentioned in the answer only because that's what my research dug up), but if there _were_ gate-crashers they wouldn't have done business with you. If they had, they'd have been ticket-holders.

Comment: Disagree — gate-crasher often has a negative connotation, particularly with regard to disruption caused by the entry.

Comment: @Dúthomhas With what statement do you disagree? I don't see anything in the question or answer that indicates a positive or neutral connotation.

Comment: I disagree with this being a good match for the OP’s situation, which is not described as negative in the way that _gate-crasher_ typically indicates. Dry links to Dictionary.com leave out [idiomatic value](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gate-crasher) common in use.

Comment: @Dúthomhas At this point in time I don't see _any_ answers that have been posted without a negative connotation. And not all gate-crashers are as noisy and rude as the ones in your link. Sometimes the negative connotation is just that they are taking up space and making the place more crowded.

Comment: The fact that all of these words have negative connotations probably says something about the culture of English speaking societies... at least in my own experience this behavior is not viewed very favorably since people could reasonably believe you're benefiting from something for which you didn't contribute like other participants. I would be surprised to see positive or even neutral words to describe this sort of thing, even if the original question doesn't describe the situation negatively.

Comment: The -crasher part of this noun is also semi-productive, so you have [party crashers](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/party-crasher), [wedding crashers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedding_Crashers), [yard crashers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yard_Crashers), and even [class-crashers](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/local/1994/04/21/class-crashers-get-the-boot/e630d120-8daa-45f9-a44d-12778b4f389e/).

Comment: FWIW, this 30-something American would spell it without the hyphen: "gatecrasher". (But: party crasher, wedding crasher. And if I needed to talk about a "class-crasher" I'd hyphenate.)

Comment: I don't really see "gate crasher" as having any more of a negative connotation than "one who sneaks into and stays in places where they [weren't] invited".  As for the issue that this isn't used with regard to theater performances, I agree (as those are not primarily social functions: it is theoretically possible to be the only person in attendance), but that isn't explicitly part of the original question.

Comment: "Theater hopping" in the context of movie theaters, used in the US.  This usually infers you pay for one movie, then at the end sneak into the next theater for a second movie you didn't pay for.  Oh, there is an answer for this below. But since the context is so narrow, I thought it only warranted a comment.

Answer (score 37):

An *interloper*, perhaps?

> **interloper** noun [ C ] disapproving
>   ​
>   someone who becomes involved in an activity or a social group without being asked, or enters a place without permission:
>
> - Security did not prevent an interloper from getting onto the stage at the opening ceremony.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interloper)

Comment: I think this is certainly the most interesting answer, and the best single word for the question :D    Other answers are also useful :)

Comment: I came to provide this answer.

Comment: I came to post this.

Comment: An interloper interferes in some way, though. They get into things or between people and have some (presumably negative) influence.

Comment: from OPs own example, the ideas is that they can interfere. I had two people interloping a seminar recently. They did interfere with the speaker's focus. Even if the interloper does not intend to and does not actively interfere, they still can have an effect, however subtle it may be.

Comment: No offence meant, but the phrase "interloping a seminar" gives me some room to wonder about your familiarity with the word.

Answer (score 19):

The related activity of taking advantage of what is free is sometimes called **freeloading** and the person who does it is called a **[freeloader](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/freeloader)**.

From the Oxford English Dictionary:

> freeloader, *n.*
>   
> *colloq.* (orig. *U.S.*).
>   
> Originally: a person who takes full advantage of the free food or drink available at a public occasion. Later more generally: a person who partakes of something offered free of charge without giving anything in return; a sponger, a scrounger.

That said, I would use the word a little more broadly to potentially include your use case as well, as one of the OED's own examples shows it being used:

> 1979    D. Adams *Hitch Hiker's Guide to Galaxy* vi. 48    I didn't become captain of a Vogon constructor ship simply so I could turn it into a taxi service for a load of degenerate **freeloaders**.

The context of this quote makes it clear that they are not simply "taking advantage of free food or drink available", but that they have *trespassed* by *sneaking surreptitiously* on board as *stowaways* (to allude to some of the other answers' more specific terms for this activity in the case of a ship).

> First of all I see from our instruments that we have a couple of hitchhikers aboard. Hello wherever you are. I just want to make it totally clear that you are not at all welcome. I worked hard to get where I am today, and I didn’t become captain of a Vogon constructor ship simply so I could turn it into a taxi service for a load of degenerate freeloaders. I have sent out a search party, and as soon as they find you I will put you off the ship. If you’re very lucky I might read you some of my poetry first.
>   
> <sub>— *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, Chapter 6*</sub>

*Edit:* I also like (perhaps prefer) Acccumulation's "free rider", which is at least as appropriate in this context in that it suggests illegitimate entry.

Comment: Also: *free rider*, *moocher*

Comment: "Freeloader" refers to taking advantage, possibly unfairly, but not necessarily without invitation/authorization.

Comment: @WGroleau: Not *necessarily*; but possibly.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me; I would understand this to mean what the OP wants more clearly than any of the other options given.

Answer (score 17):

Another colloquial verb is **to crash**.

> They crashed the wedding, pretending to be relatives of the groom.

Comment: Yes, but normally, you don't crash a course. It really is only in the contexts of parties.

Comment: https://thebottomline.as.ucsb.edu/2010/09/the-five-rules-for-crashing-classes

Comment: @Lambie Yes, it doesn't fit the meaning asked for, but no, crashing a course is a thing. It refers to attending a (full) course you aren't enrolled in with the intention of getting enrolled in the course.

Comment: So basically you can crash the crash course in crashing courses

Answer (score 12):

There are a number of possible words that apply, some more picturesque than others.

To "impersonate" means to pretend to be someone you are not:

> She **impersonated** a student in the class in order to get free instruction.

"Pose" also works:

> She **posed** as a club member in order to eat at their free buffet.

"Fake" (or "pretend") is a common term for this:

> To the casual observer, she was just another student on campus, but she was only **faking/pretending** in order to take classes without paying tuition.

"Sneak in" can be used to indicate illicit and furtive activity:

> She would often **pretend** to be an usher in order to **sneak into** the concert hall and watch performances for free.

Other possibilities:  *infiltrate, disguise (oneself) as, insinuate into, worm into, put up a front, playact, feign*, etc.

Comment: I think *imposter* might also work.

Answer (score 7):

This only works in an academic/classroom context, but you could say you were "**auditing**" the class (in contrast to those on the class roster).

Of course, most schools actually have *policies* about auditing (permission of the instructor, etc.), so if you haven't actually obtained the proper permission, then "auditing" is just a euphemism for "sneaking into class".

**EDIT**: To expand on my "euphemism" comment above, clearly sneaking in without permission *is not actual* (legitimate) auditing, per the rules of whatever school or class we're talking about. If I were writing a descriptive essay, I probably wouldn't use this term, unless I was quoting the excuse the student gave when he or she was caught.

But the term might still be well understood as "attending class for no credit", especially with other cues. Here's an example:

I run into a friend who says they saw me with a group at the local university's tennis courts. They ask, "I thought you already graduated, are you back in school?"

I might respond, "Nah, I'm just (fingerquotes) *auditing* the class".

The "fingerquotes" (or just perhaps a certain vocal intonation) are a hint that I'm using the term euphemistically, and the most plausible interpretation of that in this context is that I'm *unofficially* (without approval) attending the class; i.e. just sneaking in.

Comment: Auditing is appropriate for one who attends a class under such situations, but it doens't incorporate the "sneaking" part of this. If you told me you were auditing a class, I'd assume your presence there was authorized, or at least not forbidden. If you want to emphasize the forbidden nature of your activities, you'd need another word.

Comment: I considered this as well (and kudos to you for typing it out), but indeed, I would interpret this as an **allowed** situation. Probably useful as a related term, but slightly different than the way the question is phrased.

Comment: This might only be applicable to certain dialects. If you told me (native British English speaker from the Home Counties) that you were auditing a class I would assume you were part of an inspectorate that ensures quality.

Comment: Might be good to note that many universities also have formal audit policies and the same word applies.  In the case of a formal audit, you are on the roster and participate fully, but receive no credit and usually no final grade.

Comment: To the 3 comments saying the same thing: if I were speaking out loud, I would put finger-quotes around "auditing" in this context, to emphasize that this isn't an approved arrangement. Clearly the student is *not legitimately* auditing per whatever rules the school has in place, he or she is (fingerquotes) "auditing" the class; think of it more like the excuse he or she would offer if they were noticed by the teacher and asked. Using the term in this way would be understood, but is very context dependent - think of characters dialoging in a short story, not in a factually descriptive essay

Comment: As J.R. said, **auditing** isn't the right word. It doesn't mean "**sneak into**".

Comment: Can we make "bandit auditing" a thing?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the most popular term *(verb)* is "**to sneak into**". At least this is what I often hear when people get into some place, community, club, or anywhere else without being registered, not paying or being enrolled in there.

Comment: Please remove the part about academic audit. People who audit classes are officially listed as such in the registrar’s office. It’s not appropriate here; people who audit classes are supposed to be there, and they don’t simply “act as if they are part of the team."

Comment: @j.R. Excuse me, but I haven't found reference to that auditing people are officially listed or then registered. Could you point to it?

Comment: Read the last bullet [here](http://postdocs.mit.edu/career-development/taking-course-mit-guidelines-postdocs). Or look at [this page](https://cardinalatwork.stanford.edu/benefits-rewards/sweeteners/audit-stanford-academic-course). [This one](http://exploredegrees.stanford.edu/academicpoliciesandstatements/#auditingtext) is good, too.

Comment: my university as well..... auditing allowed you to participate - including complete assignments and get marks from the teacher, and get it marked on your transcript as taken for audit (so you can't take it again for a grade).  The word would also be appropriate if you did it informally, but applies both ways.

Comment: I've certainly heard people say "audit" when they are on no official roster but have simply asked the instructor if they can be there. (My close friend in university was such a person.) But in any case, I really like the "sneak into" answer because it really is what the OP is looking for — and indeed used. The premise that the meaning needs to or can be represented naturally using words of another part of speech need not be granted, as we've all done in our other answers.

Answer (score 4):

How about **trespasser**?

While the usual sense is in entering into private land, it also applies to any restricted spaces, such as a classroom or country club.

From [*Dictionary.com*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/trespasser)

Noun:

> 1.b - a wrongful entry upon the lands of another
>   2 - an encroachment or intrusion

Verb:

> 5. to encroach on a person's privacy, time, etc.; infringe (usually followed by on or upon).

Answer (score 3):

In slang, they could be a squatter or squatting. The formal definition refers to someone who is occupying property without permission (e.g. living in an abandoned building), but it can be understood in other contexts:

"Are you enrolled in this class?"
"No, I am just *squatting*."

Answer (score 2):

Andrew provided a good selection of verbs that could apply to the act being described, as well as "masquerade" suggested by Tyler, but since the question asks "How would you call a person like that?" I'm going to try suggesting some adjectives and nouns.

First up, **Fake** as an adjective would be useful. For example if a person named Janet attended a class that was supposed to be paid, but she didn't pay for it, then you could say

> Janet is a **fake** Student

This also applies to other situations, such as being a **Fake** member of a country club. On the other hand while Fake could be applied directly to Janet (Janet is fake) or used as a noun (Janet is a fake), I would interpret those statements as referring to more general character concepts than specifically sneaking into exclusive events.

In terms of nouns, one that would often work would be [**Impostor**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/impostor?s=t). There is some connotation of pretending to be a specific person (It wasn't Janet at all, but an impostor!) but it's just as valid to apply to someone pretending to more generally be part of a certain group or the like (He wasn't a student at all, but an impostor!).

Describing the action rather than the person does seem to be easier though, and allows for more nuance in regards to how they were attempting to fit in and why they were doing so. Someone who attends an event uninvited with the intent to subtly cause trouble might *infiltrate*, while one who also wants to cause more overt trouble at an uninvited event might *crash* it. But, when asked to describe "a person who deceitfully participated in an event" as "fake" or an "impostor" if there is no other detail.

Comment: Janet is attending the class; she is not faking by not paying.
If she pretended to be a student to get cheap traintickets, then she would be a fake student.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility in addition to those already listed, is 'stowaway'. Nautically it means someone who sneaks into a ship and makes the voyage without paying the fare. This does suggest passivity though, while you are actively participating, so it is not a perfect fit.

Comment: I think this term is somewhat similar, but specifically applies to someone riding a train, a boat, or similar without permission / ticket. Not to someone attending a party or other social functions.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case of sneaking into additional movies, we used to call it **theater hopping**--where you pay for one film and watch as many as you can stomach.

In a way that's the same thing you are doing, paying for some classes at the school but then attending a few extra classes for free--but I doubt "**class hopping**" will ever catch on.

Answer (score 1):

You can also be called an:

**intruder**

> verb (used with object), in·trud·ed, in·trud·ing.

1. to thrust or bring in without invitation, permission, or welcome.
2. Geology.to thrust or force into.

[Definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intruder)

Comment: This might work after the offending person was discovered.

Answer (score 1):

No one has yet suggested **surreptitiously**?

Which means to do something [*in a way that attempts to avoid notice or attention; secretively.*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/surreptitiously)

> The student surreptitiously joined the team

Comment: One can be surreptitious while having permission to be there, e.g. a [wallflower](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wallflower).

Comment: That's an adverb. Its not used to describe *people*, just some of their actions.

Comment: @T.E.D. true but I did show how the word could be used. And I am not alone, there are many answers that do not suggest nouns.

Comment: Legit, and I'm sorry for not telling them too. But you're someone who I can generally expect really good answers from. Sometimes having extra expected of you is a (very well disguised) complement.

Answer (score 0):

You could say **loitering**? Here's the **definition**;

> "stand or wait around without apparent purpose"

Another fitting word, which is also better, would be **masquerading**.

> "be **disguised** or **passed off** as something else"
>
> > "You '**masqueraded**' as a member of the athletic class."

This sentence works, because of whatever **situation** put you there, you still **played along** as one of the classmates.

Comment: The question clearly includes the *purpose* behind the deceit, though, so I don't think "loiter" is appropriate, but *masquerade* might work, "she **masqueraded** as a student in the class in order to get free instruction"

Comment: The OP does have a purpose.

Comment: I would upvote *masquerade* were it not for the part about *loitering* at the beginning of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, we might call such a person a **blagger**, someone who has **blagged their way** into something.